# How should I migrate a React site that uses Redux-Saga for long operations to React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

There are so many tutorials all preaching slightly different standards and conventions, what is the best practise for migrating Redux Saga to React hooks?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Shall I change the question to 'How do I use Redux Saga with React hooks?' @Rob? My answer is not best practice, it is just a possibly handy reference and format hint.

Comment: Yes, the question is _incredibly_ vague.  Please make it much more specific.  Even the alternate question you listed isn't very clear. React hooks and Redux Sagas have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: When there is more than one acceptable way to do something then how one should do something becomes opinion and that is an issue with this.

Comment: What I want to know is how to migrate a React site that uses Redux-Saga for long operations to React hooks, but I am struggling to phrase this as a closed question.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the approach I'm using, pre-hooks.

## Redux Store

#### Action name - `constants/index.js`

```
export const SET_NARRATIVE = 'SET_NARRATIVE'
```

#### Action Creator - `actions/narrative.js`

Components call this to dispatch an action

```
export const setNarrative = narrative => {
  return {
    type: SET_NARRATIVE,
    narrative,
  }
}
```

Making this `narrativeSet` would better match the Saga naming convention, but isn't so readable in components.

#### Reducer - `reducers/narrative.js`

Spots dispatched action and applies update from component to store.

```
export const narrativeReducer = (state = narrativeInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case SET_NARRATIVE:
    return {
      ...state,
      narrative: action.narrative,
    } ...
```

#### Combine reducers - `reducers/index.js`

Hook Reducer into Redux action / event loop

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  narrative: narrativeReducer,
```

#### Components - `components/Draft.js`

Connect the component to the Redux state and dispatcher. Think best practice is to use `containers/` for connected components, but most of my components are connected.

Read from `this.props.narrative` , write using `this.props.setNarrative(narrative)`.

```
import { setNarrative } from '../actions/narrative'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  narrative: state.narrative.narrative,  // processing here if necessary
})
const mapDispatchToProps = { setNarrative }
Draft = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Draft)
export default Draft
```

## Redux Saga

#### Action names - `constants/index.js`

```
export const NARRATIVE_FETCH_REQUESTED = 'NARRATIVE_FETCH_REQUESTED'
export const NARRATIVE_FETCH_SUCCEEDED = 'NARRATIVE_FETCH_SUCCEEDED'
export const NARRATIVE_FETCH_FAILED = 'NARRATIVE_FETCH_FAILED'
```

#### Action Creators - `actions/narrative.js`

Actions to request a narrative by id, and 'put' the result or error.

```
export const narrativeFetchRequested = id => {
  return {
    type: NARRATIVE_FETCH_REQUESTED,
    id,
  }
}
export const narrativeFetchSucceeded = narrative => {
  return {
    type: NARRATIVE_FETCH_SUCCEEDED,
    narrative,
  }
}
export const narrativeFetchFailed = error => {
  return {
    type: NARRATIVE_FETCH_FAILED,
    error,
  }
}
```

#### Reducer clauses - `reducers/narrative.js`

Store fetch status, results and/or error in Redux Store.

```
case NARRATIVE_FETCH_REQUESTED:
  return {
    ...state,
    narrativeLoading: true,
  }
case SET_NARRATIVE: )  // non-Saga version above
case NARRATIVE_FETCH_SUCCEEDED:
  return {
    ...state,
    narrative: action.narrative,
    narrativeLoading: false,
  }
case NARRATIVE_FETCH_FAILED:
  return {
    ...state,
    narrative: null,
    narrativeLoading: false,
    error: action.error,
  }
```

#### Hook reducer into Redux action / event loop - `reducers/index.js`

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  narrative: narrativeReducer,  // as above
```

#### API layer - `api/index.js`

```
export const getNarrative = id => {
  return axios.get(`${API_URL}narratives/${id}/`)
}
```

#### Sagas - `sagas/narrative.js`

Send request to API, process data returned, then dispatch (put) action to update store.

```
export function* fetchNarrative(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action
    const { data: narrative } = yield call(getNarrative, id)
    createPermissionShortcuts(narrative)  // some off-thread processing
    narrative.updated_display = renderDate(narrative.updated) // Python backend naming convention
    yield put(fetchNarrativeSucceeded(narrative))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchNarrativeFailed(error))
  }
}
export function* watchNarrativeRequested() {
  yield takeEvery(NARRATIVE_FETCH_REQUESTED, fetchNarrative)
}
```

#### Hook Saga into dispatcher - `sagas/index.js`

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    watchNarrativeRequested(),
    ...
```

#### Running Saga

In `containers/App.js` to run a Saga when the app starts:

```
sagaMiddleware.run(fetchNarrative)  // to trigger on app start
```

..and/or..

In `components/Section.js` to run from a component:

- Trigger using `this.props.fetchNarrativeRequested(id)`
- While loading, `this.props.narrativeLoading === true`
- When loaded, read from `this.props.narrative`
- If failed, read error from `this.props.narrativeError`

```
class Section extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() { // in your component - render then fetch
    this.props.narrativeFetchRequested(this.props.match.params.id) //if router parse url
  } ...
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    narrative: state.narrative.narrative,
    narrativeLoading: state.narrative.narrativeLoading,
    narrativeError: state.narrative.error,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  narrativeFetchRequested,
}
Section = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Section)
export default Section
```